# javascript evaluation failed: PPB00001694, ReferenceError: "PPB00001694" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1

Tags: karate

I have created a test using Karate DSL and using the data-table for the send to the URL path variable. I need to pass the test data in to URL, but it's throwing an error.

**My code:**

```
Feature: Update the test details test.
Background:
Scenario: Update test
  Scenario Outline: Update the existing test details with the tab.

    Given url URL
    And path 'vouchers/' ,'exams/' ,'<exam_code>'
    And request {isExmConfigured:true,examDescription:'Hello',  examCode:'NGH9CPDN',examExternalCode: 'SOA-P00',examName: "Jagannatha Test Code",isVisible: true}
    When method PUT
    Then status 200
  And print 'response: ', response
  Examples: | exam_code |
            | PPB00001694 |
```

**Error trace:**

```
updatetest.feature:4 - javascript evaluation failed: PPB00001694, ReferenceError: "PPB00001694" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
HTML report: (paste into browser to view) | Karate version: 0.9.4
```